# Conditional where clause with date parameters raises a has no supported translation to SQL. error in Linq to SQL with C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I'm working on a linq to sql project using Visual C# 2008 and dot Net framework 4.5.
    my query is as follows

```
var q =
        from a in dc.GetTable<invoice_in>()
        join b in dc.GetTable<supplier>()
        on a.supplier_id equals b.id
        where a.invoice_date >= date_from
        select new Invoice_in(a.id, a.amount ?? 0, a.invoice_number ,
                              a.supplier_id ?? 0, a.supplier.s_name,
                              a.invoice_date ?? System.DateTime.Today);
```

invoce_in is a linq class while Invoice_in is a class I defined with a similar structure.
When I put the date comparison inside where clause within the last query, everything is OK. But I need to use a conditional where, as the query parameters goes after the main query clause

I added the following lines to the previous code

```
if (date_from != null)
        {
            q = q.Where(w => w.invoice_date >= date_from);
        }
```

Where w.invoice_date is of DateTime type and it is data member of the class Invoice_in (defined by me).
Adding that last lines of code causes the following runtime error:
"has no supported translation to SQL"

I've tried dozens of methods on the web such as using SQLMethods for comparing dates and such stuff, nothing works

Please Help... Thanks in advance...

Comment: Why won't you add your condition on date_from inside your linq query?
`where (date_from == null || a.invoice_date >= date_from)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
var q =
    from a in dc.GetTable<invoice_in>()
    join b in dc.GetTable<supplier>()
        on a.supplier_id equals b.id
    select a;

//since you compared date_from against null I assume it is Nullable<DateTime>
if (date_from.HasValue)
    {
        q = q.Where(a => a.invoice_date >= date_from.Value);
    }

var result = 
q.Select(a => new Invoice_in(a.id, a.amount ?? 0, 
                             a.invoice_number ,
                             a.supplier_id ?? 0, 
                             a.supplier.s_name,
                             a.invoice_date ?? System.DateTime.Today))
 .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It helped but I removed the value property of date_from because it's a DateTime objecy. But what is the difference? why executing the select at the end solved it ?

Comment: during `Invoice_in` object creation you use `a.invoice_date ?? System.DateTime.Today` and next compare it with 'date_from' in where condition - this cannot be properly parsed. BTW, `q` is queryable, so you don't get the data from database until you enumerate it (`ToList()` in our case). It might be reasonable to first enumerate the `q` and then select new `Invoice_in` like following: `var result = q.ToList().Select(a => new Invoice_in(...));` it should perform faster.